# Recursive functions in OCaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml, stack-overflow

I have a little problem: I want to solve [this problem](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=1) with OCaml,
so I tried this ->

```
-> let rec somme x = if ( nor (bool_of_int (x mod 3)) (bool_of_int (x mod 5))) then x + (somme x-1) else (somme x-1) ;;

val somme : int -> int = <fun>

-> somme 1000 ;;

Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?).
```

What have I done wrong ?

---

New code I tried:

```
let somme2 x = if (( nor (bool_of_int (x mod 3)) (bool_of_int (x mod 5)))) then x + somme (x-1) else somme (x-1) ;;

let somme x = if x = 0 then x else somme2 x ;;
```

Same error.

Comment: The main thing I spot you've done wrong is trying to solve that problem using a recursive function...

Comment: You should have restarted the caml interpreter : it uses the old definition of somme in somme2, that's why you don't need to use the rec keyword in your second definition. Use let rec ... = ... and ... = ... ;;
This should work, except that you should write if x= 0 then 0 else somme2 x, because the "return x" is confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) your recusion never stops add a test like `if x == 0 then 0 else ...` at the beginning

2) you don't put parentheses around your `x-1`, so ocaml reads `(somme x)-1`. Write `somme (x-1)` instead.

Comment: tried this:
let somme2 x = if (( nor (bool_of_int (x mod 3)) (bool_of_int (x mod 5)))) then x + somme (x-1) else somme (x-1) ;;

let somme x = if x = 0 then x else somme2 x ;;

but same thing.

Answer (score 2):

As other have pointed out, you should include a test for the base case. You can use pattern matching:

```
match x with
| 0 -> ...
| n -> ...;;
```

Functional languages often mirror closely mathematical notation, and pattern matching actually resembles closely the way you would write the equations on paper.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution to the problem, maybe it will help you improve your OCaml skills

```
(*generates a list of the multiples of num and stops at max*)
let gen_mult num max=

  let rec gen i=

  if i*num>=max then []

  else (i*num)::gen (i+1)

  in gen 1;;

let m3=gen_mult 3 1000;;

let m5=gen_mult 5 1000;;

(*sums the multiples of 3*)
let s3=List.fold_left (fun acc x->x+acc) 0 m3;;

(*sums the multiples of 5 except those of 3*)
let s5=List.fold_left (fun acc x->if x mod 3=0 then acc else x+acc) 0 m5;;

let result=s3+s5;;
```

Answer (score 2):

No terminating condition on the loop.  To fix your code:

```
let rec somme1 x = 
  if x <= 0
    then 0
    else if ((x mod 3) = 0) or ((x mod 5) = 0)
      then x + (somme1 (x-1))
      else somme1 (x-1);;

somme1 1000;;
```

To improve your code, you'd make your function tail-recursive.

```
let rec somme2 x accum = 
  if x <= 0
    then accum
    else if ((x mod 3) = 0) or ((x mod 5) = 0)
      then somme2 (x-1) (accum+x)
      else somme2 (x-1) accum

somme2 1000 0;;
```

The difference between the two versions is that, in the tail-recursive case, the results of the recursive call are precisely the same as the result of the function, so no intermediate state needs to be stored to finish the calculation after the recursive function is called.  When you call `somme1 1000;;` then, because `(1000 mod 5 == 0) or (1000 mod 3 == 0)` evaluates `true`, you get the recursive call `1000 + (somme1 999)`, which, to complete, requires the recursive call `999 + (somme1 998)`.  The compiler has to keep the numbers `1000` and `999` around on the stack until `somme1` finishes executing, which it doesn't (no terminating condition), so your stack fills up trying to store `1000 + (999 + (996 + (995 + ...`.

This will be equivalent to `((((0 + 1000) + 999) + 996) + 995) + ...`, but in this case there are no intermediate values needed to work on the result of the recursive calls (that is, the return value of the recursive call is the same as the return value of the function itself), so no additional stack space is necessary.  The second version works this way.  If it had the same bug as the first, it would not have run out of stack, but would have just continued executing indefinitely.  This is considered an improvement. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know zip about OCaml, but it looks like your code has no terminating condition for the recursion.

Comment: good idea. I tried this:
let rec somme x = if (( nor (bool_of_int (x mod 3)) (bool_of_int (x mod 5))) & (x > 0)) then x + (somme x-1) else (somme x-1) ;;
but it still doesn't works.

Comment: If the  terminating condition is true, you must not call the function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see any termination condition in the code above? Normally, I'd expect the recursion to stop for a certain value of x, possibly 0 or 1. Your code doesn't seem to include any provision like this.

Please keep in mind that I know as much about OCaml as Neil admits to.

Answer (score 0):

try to use pattern matching and filtering parameter 
syntax:

```
let f a= match a with
| a when (a=..)  -> ...
| a when (a=..)-> ...
| _ -> ...;;

let f = function
   p1 -> expr1
 | p2 -> expr2
 | p3 -> ...;;
```

The solution:

---

```
let mult_3or5  a = match a with
  a when ((a mod 3=0)||(a mod 5=0)) ->true
 |_  ->false;;
```

---

```
let rec somme_mult_3or5 = function 
    a when (a=0) -> failwith "Indice invalide"    
   |a when (a=1) -> 0
   |a -> if (mult_3or5 (a-1)=true) then ((a-1)+ somme_mult_3or5 (a-1)) 
         else somme_mult_3or5 (a-1);;
```

Comment: OCaml is for lazy typers, we think less chars are easier to read. Line 4: ... `if mult_3or5 (a-1) then' ..